# MYSQL TOTAL MULTIPLE UNIQUE COLUMN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got some data like this

```
=================================
COL A | COL B | COL C | VAL
=================================
  5   |   6   |   3   |  2
  2   |   6   |   3   |  3
  5   |   6   |   3   |  4
  5   |   6   |   1   |  5
```

What I want to do is total All the Value in Column VAL ONLY if the column Has Uniquq Value Combination.

In Above Case The Total is 2 + 3 + 5 = 10
The Third Row isn't counted because the combination of 5 6 3 is not unique.

I've tried GROUP BY COL A,COL B,COL C, it will result

```
=================================
COL A | COL B | COL C | VAL
=================================
  5   |   6   |   3   |  2
  2   |   6   |   3   |  3
  5   |   6   |   1   |  5
```

The thing is I dont know how to get the total of it.
I've tried WITH ROLLUP, somehow it makes the table messy.

Any help is Appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have a tie-break problem here. So your question cannot be answered

Comment: sum on the result of `GROUP BY COL A,COL B,COL C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the combination is not unique, which value do you choose?  Remember, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no notion of one row being before or after another.

According to your example, the following works:

```
select sum(val)
from (select a, b, c, min(val) as val
      from t
      group by a, b, c
     ) t;
```

Comment: Actually I dont really care about the order.

Comment: tested it, this is what I am looking for. Thanks for the help. I don't know why my question get downvote.